# Arrayformat on a DATETIME Cell

Tags: google-sheets

Im using Google Sheets where i have a cell with a datetime.

I got this information in my cell.
2014-01-31 15:00:51 +0100

I want to split it up in two cells so i got a cell with the date and a cell with the time.

Is there some easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=ArrayFormula(regexreplace(A3&"", "(.+)\s(.+\s.+)", {"$1", "$2"}))
```

where A3 is the cell to split.

Or for a range of cells:

```
=ArrayFormula(regexreplace(A3:A18&"", "(.+)\s(.+\s.+)", {"$1", "$2"}))
```